# Proper way to build URL containing dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to query an API where I need to fill in the `partNumber` and `manufacturer`.

Say I need to fill in the partNumber to be bav99 and `NXP Semiconductors` to be the manufacturer. The final result should look like below:

```
https://app.datafireball.com/SearchService/search/listPartSearch?
partNumber=[{
%22partNumber%22:%22bav99wt%22,
%22manufacturer%22:%22NXP%20Semiconductors%22}]&
fmt=xml
```

I have to say I got really confused by the fact that which characters should be encoded and which not. Based on what I have seen, the double quote `"` should be encoded into `%22` and space be encoded into `%20`.

What I have done:

```
import urllib
urltemplate = """https://app.datafireball.com/SearchService/search/listPartSearch?partNumber=[{{%22partNumber%22:%22{0}%22,%22manufacturer%22:%22{1}%22}}]&fmt=xml"""
# I have to recode the curly brackets to be double curly brackets, otherwise place holder won't work.
url = urltemplate.format(urllib.quote('my partnumber'), urllib.quote('my manufacturer') )
print url
```

I guess I can summarize my concerns into two following questions:

1. why should certain characters be encoded and some not.
2. what is the proper way and practical way to encode the object instead of using place holder to hard code it.

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) help you ...

> urllib.urlencode(query[, doseq])¶
>
> ```
> Convert a mapping object or a sequence of two-element tuples 
> to a “percent-encoded” string, suitable to pass to urlopen() above as the
> optional data argument. This is useful to pass a dictionary of form
> fields to a POST request.
> ```